# Mock server and the service called

Tags: spring-boot

Apologise if this question has already been answered or this is too trivial, but I am a new on this subject and couldn't find the answer.
To simplify, here is a sample code taken from the Spring Boot Ref ( https://github.com/philwebb/testing-spring-boot-applications ) :

The test :

```
@Test
public void getVehicleDetailsWhenResultIsSuccessShouldReturnDetails() throws Exception {
    this.server..expect(requestTo("http://example.com/vehicle/" + VIN + "/details"))
        .andRespond(withSuccess(getClassPathResource("vehicledetails.json"),
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));                        // 1
    VehicleDetails details = this.service
            .getVehicleDetails(new VehicleIdentificationNumber(VIN));    // 2
    assertThat(details.getMake()).isEqualTo("Honda");                    // 3
}
```

The service :

```
@Override
public VehicleDetails getVehicleDetails(VehicleIdentificationNumber vin)
    throws VehicleIdentificationNumberNotFoundException {
    Assert.notNull(vin, "VIN must not be null");
    String url = this.properties.getRootUrl() + "vehicle/{vin}/details";
    try {
        return this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, VehicleDetails.class, vin);
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
        if (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(ex.getStatusCode())) {
            throw new VehicleIdentificationNumberNotFoundException(vin, ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

My questions is if we remove line 1, what will happen then ? Shouldn't give the same purpose ? What is the relationship between line 1 and 2 ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Line 1 sets up the "server" mock object so that line 2 will know what to do when it is executed.  It's a fairly typical example of a mock setup, though in this particular instance it appears to be testing the mock rather than any code under test.

Comment: How line 2 will know what to do since line 1 and line 2 are completely independant ? I mean, the 'server' instance is not used at all in line 2.

So, for 'code under test', it is not useful to setup the mock server (line 1), or is it ?

Comment: Without more code context, it's hard to say.  I suspect that `server` and `service` are related in some way.

Comment: I edited my question, the full source code is on github.

Comment: Anyone can help me ? Thanks.